# Haskell projects to study and learn from?

Tags: haskell, open-source

As a developer who is new to Haskell, I am looking for open-source
Haskell applications that I could study and learn from.

In particular, I am looking for open-source projects that show:

- How to write network servers that scale well, with low response
  latencies and high throughput.
  The [Warp](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/03/preliminary-warp-cross-language-benchmarks) webserver would
  perhaps be an example here, are there any others?
- Applications showing techniques for keeping memory use low, or
  showing examples of GC-friendly design.
- Projects that showcase techniques for testing Haskell applications
  (related question: [haskell-testing-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120796/haskell-testing-workflow)).
- Programs designed for running well on multi-core systems.

What open-source projects would you recommend as exemplars of modern
Haskell programming?

Related SO question: [good-haskell-source-to-read-and-learn-from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398996/good-haskell-source-to-read-and-learn-from).

Comment: And second this question AND re-ask it for Common Lisp. I need some *real* experience, not just short toy problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as network servers go, I suggest reading *Mighttpd – a High Performance Web Server in Haskell* by Kazu Yamamoto, from [issue 19 of the Monad.Reader](http://themonadreader.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/issue-19/); it uses Warp under the hood and can achieve speeds exceeding that of nginx(!). That same issue also has an article about [Haskell-MPI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-mpi), so it's relevant for multi-core programming too.

The [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) source code is frequently recommended (e.g. in the related question you linked), as it is a widely-used, stable piece of "real-world" software with an unusual amount of care and attention paid to good Haskell design.

Answer (score 4):

I learned a lot from hacking a bit on [hledger](http://hledger.org/).